Teradata: Is there a way to get table names & row count for a given database (without using the stats table?)
Teradata: Is there a way to get table names & row count for a given database
(without using the stats table?),
BTW: Stats table are stale in most of the production environment !
perhaps using 2 SQLs ?, hope some Teradata expert can help

select databasename ||.||tablename as DBTableName from dbc.TablesV WHERE tablekind='T' AND databasename IN ('db1','db2')
select count(*) from DBTableName

select count(*) from DBTableName (
select databasename||.||tablename as DBTableName from dbc.TablesV WHERE tablekind='T'
)

You need to use a Stored Procedure or client-side script to dynamically generate and run a SELECT for each table. For a Stored Procedure, you would likely INSERT SELECT the results into a (temporary) table and then return a "dynamic result set" with all the values.

thankyou Fed, I thought there is a simpler option
